# What is the difference between content="IE=edge" & content="IE=10"

Tags: html, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11

My interanet site not loading in edge mode. But it's working fine in chrome and Firefox. Can some one help me out on this. I am using IE 11 windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version of Internet Explorer you're using. If you're using Internet Explorer 10, or less, they're identical. If, however, you are using Internet Explorer 11, they are very different.

The `IE=edge` portion instructs the browser to go into the latest supported Document Mode; for Internet Explorer 11, this is the IE11 Document Mode. In contrast, `IE=10` instructs the browser to go into Internet Explorer 10 Document Mode.

In browsers prior to Internet Explorer 10, that also support the meta-tag, or equivalent HTTP response header, both approaches will trigger the latest possible document mode. All other browsers will fall into IE 5 Quirks Mode, if I am not mistaken.

I would encourage you to *only* use `IE=edge`, to ensure users on Internet Explorer 11 get the most modern experience possible. The relevance of this stops with Internet Explorer 11 though. With the roll-out of Windows 10, Microsoft Edge will succeed Internet Explorer, and does not support document modes at all.

Be sure to use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype, as this helps ensure your users get the best experience in Internet Explorer. The `x-ua-compatible` meta-tag/header are intended only to temporarily restore functionality to a site while the site itself can be brought up to date with modern standards.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Is IE edge is kind of restrict mode? like use strict in js. Can't find why the page keep crashing

Comment: No, "Edge" in this context means greater support for more standards and features. Document Modes lower than "Edge" yield fewer and fewer features, standards, and improvements.

Comment: Can i have IE edge & IE 10 content in metatag? Just to make sure fallback if something goes wrong will fall back to IE 10.

Comment: If you put in `IE=Edge`, the *highest* document mode will be selected recent versions of Internet Explorer. You can however explicitly declare a list of fallbacks (we don't recommend this). For instance, `content="IE=7,9,10"` precludes the use of IE 8's Document Mode.